# How do I properly install the MailChimp module?

Tags: 8, installation, plugins, emails

In order to install MailChimp in Drupal 8 I followed the instructions for the [MailChimp Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp).

> **Instructions for 8.x-1.x**
>
> The 8.x-1.x release uses version 3.0 of the MailChimp API and bundles
>   the library with the module. This is a temporary solution until the
>   process for installing libraries via composer is finalized in Drupal
>   8.

1. in `admin/modules/install` I added mailchimp 8.x-1.3
2. Checked that libraries is installed (`Machine name: libraries; Version: 8.x-3.x-dev`)
3. Enabled all four modules (mailchimp, mailchimp_campaign, mailchimp_lists, mailchimp_signup)

However, when trying to **configure the module at `admin/config/services/mailchimp` the page could not be found**.

How can I resolve this issue and where should I start looking?

- PHP 7.1.6-nmm1
- Drupal 8.4.0-dev

Answer (score 0):

You should use Composer to fetch this module, as it has an external dependency noted in its `composer.json` file:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mailchimp/tree/composer.json

It seems to include an older version with the module, I'm not sure why, but the current version of Mailchimp API by Thinkshout looks to be 1.0.8. I don't see any installation notes. The module comes with 1.0.6... ?

Other than that, clear your caches and try to access the page again.